# How to use contact events

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-contacts, android-event

On my HTC Desire phone I have 'events' field on contact level. It allows to add some information to contact such as birthday and so on.
I have 2 question regarding it:

1. I cannot find such a field on Android emulator? Does it exist? If yes how to turn it on?
2. Is HTC "events" the same as Android standard (from SDK) "events" or is it HTC specific feature?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you check Android emulator which has the same Android version with your HTC phone? I checked android 4.1 emulator and it had events field.